# ActionCable broadcast with ActiveSupport::Notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

In my `config/initializers/events.rb` we have

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "post.created" do |*args|
end
```

Whenever a new post is created, we're instrumenting it as:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument("post.created", post: post)
```

Now I want to make a broadcast using `ActionCable` to all the logged in users whenever a new Post is created.

Something like

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast("new_post", post)
```

How can I go about implementing this? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to subscribe them to a channel at some point in your user flow (maybe upon login?) and then trigger the broadcast in the same controller action you created the post. Then display it via a js flash notice if you can't be sure which page they're on.

Comment: Don't I need to trigger the broadcast in the `ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe` block? This is when I'll have access to that event. Thoughts?